# SVG feTurbulance animation anchore point

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to create water effect in my application to simulate water in pool. I got animation working with feTurbelance but my top left corner is not moving and it looks like animation is toward bottom right corner where water movement is fastest. Is possible to move that source point to middle of the screen or even better to have movement same across the screen?

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://media.wired.com/photos/6021a846875aa8ef79949629/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/Sec_waterhack_71550632.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: url(#waterFilter);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>

<svg className={styles.waves__effect}>
    <defs>
        <filter id="waterFilter">
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="3" seed="3">
                <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" values="0.015; 0.0075; 0.015" dur="20s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </feTurbulence>
            <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" scale="20" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/d3nis031/pen/dyvxaXY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the `baseFrequency`, you are really just zooming in and out of the fractal noise.

A better solution would be to keep the base frequency constant, and move the noise around by using `<feOffset>`.

```
<svg className={styles.waves__effect}>
    <defs>
        <filter id="waterFilter" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.0075"
                          numOctaves="3" seed="3"/>
            <feOffset dy="0"> 
                <animate attributeName="dx" values="0; -1900; 0" dur="20s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </feOffset>
            <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" scale="20" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

What we are doing here is doubling the width of the filter: `width="200%"`
Then we shift the result of the turbulence left and right.

You could improve it by adding some movement in the vertical direction.  Or you could combine it with a second copy of the turbulence moving at a different rate and/or direction.

Comment: This is perfect! only thing is that I needed to set width on 400% because with 200% my element was shrinking down at end of cycle every time. with 400% working perfect. Thank you

Comment: The best way to animate Turbulence is by using a feColorMatrix hueRotate because it's cyclic: Example here: https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/fmJKr